# Does anyone know where I can find psql 8.x?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, psql

I am looking to download psql 8.x for Windows.  Yes, I've googled it and the only versions I can seem to find are either for *nix or 9.x.  We are using Amazon Redshift and I'd like to be able to write a plugin (or whatever they are called) for Sublime Text 3 so I can use it instead of Aginity or anything else, but that requires getting psql 8.x.  Can anyone help?

Comment: http://www.oldversion.com/windows/postgresql/  or http://www.oldapps.com/postgresql.php But a current 9.x `psql.exe` should be able to talk to a 8.x server

Comment: I thought so too, but redshift specifies you need to use psql 8.x.  Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it. You *may* be able to get help on the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use psql version 8.4.

I have extensively used psql versions 9.5 and 9.6 with redshift.